# Is there any way to install python packages through flask app?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a flask app that executes scripts using exec(script_name, globals()) and is running in Google Cloud Run using a docker. All my scripts are in Google Cloud storage. So I use gcsfs module to read the scripts from GCS and execute.

For eg:

```
exec(gcs_file_system.open(<script_from_cloud>).read(), globals())
```

But the problem I am facing is that, whenever there is a new package to be imported, I need to first install that package through my flask app using exec() function. As far, I have tried using

```
1. exec("os.system('pip install package_name')", globals())
2. exec("subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package_name])", globals())
3. import pip
   pip.main(['install', package_name])
4. import pip
   exec("pip.main(['install', package_name])", globals())
5. os.system('pip install package_name')
6. subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package_name])
```

All these were tried executing in a script script.py which i call using

```
exec(gcs_file_system.open('bucket_name..../script.py').read())
```

Everytime i try any of these, I either get an upstream disconnect error or the script simply fails. I really need some help or suggestion on how to install a package through a flask app that is running in the cloud (Google Cloud Run).

Comment: Is it work on your workstation? Did you try your container?

Comment: it works on my local machine.. but doesnot work in container

Comment: It doesn't work in a container on your local machine, right? Not really surprising, because you have your container loaded in memory, with the python runtime and you update the python runtime on the fly. Something smells like a wrong idea/design.

Comment: I fixed it by giving exec(os.system('pip install package'), globals()) in a seperate route function rather than giving it in another exec() script. It works.

Comment: Interesting. Post it as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a package can be done by defining another route function just for installing a package.

This was done by providing the below statement in a separate route function rather than specifying to install the package in another exec(script) function inside a route function.

```
exec("os.system('pip install " + str(packages) + "')", globals())
```

Server.py

```
@app.route('/add_package', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_package():
    return render_template('add_package.html')


@app.route('/add_package_success', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_package_success():
    code_content = request.form.get("code_editor", "").split("\n")
    for empties in range(code_content.count("")):
        code_content.remove("")
    code_content = [packages.strip().replace("\n", "") for packages in code_content]
    for packages in code_content:
        exec("os.system('pip install " + str(packages) + "')", globals())
    return render_template('add_package_success.html')
```

add_package.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add Packages</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/codemirror.css') }}">
    <script type="text/javascript"
         src="{{ url_for('static', filename='codemirror.js') }}"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript"
         src="{{ url_for('static', filename='python.js') }}"></script>
    <style>
        .center {
            width: 15%;
            border: 2.5px solid red;
        }
        .header{
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            position: relative;
            left: 10%;
        }
        .body_text{
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        .info_div{
            height: 180px;
            width: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50px;
            display: none;
            z-index:100;
        }
        .info{
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;
            background-color: yellow;
            position: relative;
            left: 30px;
            border: solid red;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight bold;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        .info:hover{
            cursor: help;
        }
        .info:hover + .info_div{
            display: block;
        }
        .submit_btn_2 {
            color: white;
            border: solid;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #003280;
            width: 170px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        .submit_btn_2:hover {
            background-color: #575558;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/add_package_success" method="post">
    <div class="center">
        <p class='header'>Add Packages</p><input class='info' value='?' readonly<br/><br/>
    </div><br/>
    <div>
        <a class="body_text" style="border: 2px #020d36 solid;color: #3a18a5;text-align: left;">Enter the Packages name (one in each line): </a><br/><br/>
        <textarea name="code_editor" id="code_editor"></textarea><br/><br/>
        <button type="submit">Add</button><br/><br/>
        <button formaction="/" style="left: 0px; top: 10px; width: 100px; height: 30px;" class = "submit_btn_2" type="submit"> Home </button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
<script>
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code_editor"), {
        mode: {name: "python",
               version: 3,
               singleLineStringErrors: false},
        lineNumbers: true,
        indentUnit: 4,
        matchBrackets: true
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

add_package_success.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Code Edited</title>
</head>
<body onload="load_function()">
</body>
<script>
    function load_function(){
        if(alert("Package Installed.\n\nPress OK to go HOME.")){
            window.location.href = "{{ url_for('index') }}";
        }
        window.location.href = "{{ url_for('index') }}";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

index.html

```
<form method='post' action='/'>
    <button class = "submit_btn_2" formaction="/add_package" id='add_package' style="position: absolute; top: 210px; left:1230px; height: 30px;" name="add_package">Install Packages</button>
</form>
```